# Why do I get an HTTP 404 on this one Web API request?

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api, dotnet-httpclient, asp.net-web-api-routing

I am making a `POST` request, and getting a `404 - Not Found` error back, to this controller and action:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefix("api/Appt")]
public class AppointmentController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public AppointmentDto Post(AppointmentDto model)
    {
        Db.Appointments.Add(model);
        Db.SaveChanges();
        Logger.Info($"Appointment ID {model.Id} created.");
        return model;
    }
}
```

The request is made from a WPF client using `HttpClient` from the `Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Client` package. The client is configured like so:

```
public abstract class BaseRestClient
{
    protected const string BaseAddress = "http://localhost:51009";
    protected HttpClient Client;

    protected virtual void ConfigureClient()
    {
        Client = new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(BaseAddress) };
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
        Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
    }
}
```

And called as follows:

```
var response = await Client.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Appt", model, cancellationToken);
```

Properties on `response` include:

```
StatusCode: 404`
ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found'`
RequestMessage: 
    {Method: POST, RequestUri: 'http://localhost:51009/api/Appt'`
```

This is the only request I'm making to a `POST` action, with a `model` parameter, but, ironically, a `POST` request to a `GET` action on an almost identical controller works fine. With the controller:

```
[System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefix("api/Person")]
public class PersonController : BaseController
{
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IEnumerable<PersonDto>> Get()
    {
        Db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return await Db.Persons.ToListAsync();
    }
}
```

the request made as below works fine and returns all my `Person` objects:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = await Client.PostAsync("api/Person", null, cancellationToken);
```

Two similar requests to `GET` actions also work perfectly.

So why would the one resource be found, and the other not? Are the any other, hidden reasons a 404 would be returned other than the requested resource not being found?

Could this be due to a conflict with two types of routing, e.g.

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

I have to use attribute routing in one place, the comment explains why:

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("Get")] 
// NOTE HTTP 405 - Method not allowed when this action is named 'Get'.
public async Task<IEnumerable<BranchDto>> Fetch()
{
    Db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
    return await Db.Branches.ToListAsync();
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the wrong route prefix attribute.

```
System.Web.Mvc.RoutePrefix("api/Appt")
```

is for **MVC** not Web API.

You need the one in `System.Web.Http`

```
System.Web.Http.RoutePrefix("api/Appt")
```

The reason the person controller example worked is because it defaulted back to convention-based routing.

original would have worked if you called `POST http://localhost:51009/api/Appointment` via convention-based routing.